# Codeigniter cart Library not working properly

Tags: codeigniter

I have used cart library for adding updating and deleting items in carts. I am counting number cart items not quantity. I am counting number of item in navigation header which will be including in all pages. But when i navigate to different pages cart item will not be the same. If i added 2 items in cart in home page it shows 2. when i navigate to about us page it it will automatically setting to 1. if i use cart count why it will display different count in different page? Help me with this.

Comment: Use common header for all pages

Comment: i am using same header for every page.

Comment: Show code of home page and about page (controllers, models, views, etc, anything relevant). Check [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) how you should actually ask.